# How to use Mingw with a build system in Sublime Text

Tags: c++, output, sublimetext3, user-input, mingw-w64

I am using Sublime Text and learning C++. I installed Mingw (also added path) and Sublime Text and added a new build system for taking the external output and input.

Here is the code:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["g++ -std=c++14 '$file_name' -o '$file_base_name' && timeout 4s ./'$file_base_name'<input.txt>output.txt"], 
    "selector" : "source.c, source.cpp",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

After pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, it threw an error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:D:\Anand\competitive programming\input.txt: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:D:\Anand\competitive programming\input.txt:1: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "D:\Anand\competitive programming\input.txt" -o "D:\Anand\competitive programming/input" && "D:\Anand\competitive programming/input"]
[dir: D:\Anand\competitive programming]
[path: C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\MinGW\bin]
```

```
Error 2:

The system cannot find the path specified.
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ["g++ -std=c++14 'HelloWorld.cpp' -o 'HelloWorld' && timeout 4s ./'HelloWorld'<input.txt>output.txt"]]
[dir: D:\Anand\competitive programming]
[path: C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\MinGW\bin]
```

Comment: The command posted in your build system doesn't match the command that was actually executed; I'd double check that you have the correct build system selected. The output also shows that you're trying to compile the `txt` file; you should select the file you're trying to compile and then select the build command.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the single quotes surrounding the `$` variables, and you don't need the `./`, as you're running Windows. Edit your build system to include the following:

```
"cmd" : ["g++ -std=c++14 $file_name -o $file_base_name && timeout 4s $file_base_name < input.txt > output.txt"],
```

and you should be all set.